# How to prevent a transition delay

Tags: css, delay, transition

I have been playing with a CSS transition for a nav menu found at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ny06Le/1/).  The same code can be found below:

EDIT: [Updated jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ny06Le/2/)

CSS:

```
nav {
    background-color: #337AB7;
    position: relative;
}

nav:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}

nav h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

nav #nav-toggle {
    display: none;
}

nav label[for='nav-toggle']:after {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: .5em;
    width: 4em;
    content: 'Menu';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

nav ul {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;



    transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

nav #nav-toggle:checked ~ ul {
    max-height: 1000px;

    transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

nav #nav-toggle:checked ~ label:after {
    content: 'Close';
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #337AB7;
}

nav li {
    margin: .5em 0;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active,
nav a:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #337AB7;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
   <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
   <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
   <label for="nav-toggle"></label>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

The opening transition is working correctly, but when closing the menu there is some kind of delay before the transition actually happens.  How do I stop this delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your animation is taking so long is because you are transitioning `max-height`.  Even though your end height is only 134px, you're not transitioning that.  It's doing the transition for the full 1000px you have `max-height` set to.  This doesn't look like anything is wrong when it expands, but when it closes it is starting at 1000 and counting down.  Which looks like it's being delayed, even though it's not.  It's just not having an effect on the actual height until it gets to about 134px.  If you change it to height and transition that instead the issue is fixed.  Just lower your height to a more manageable level.

You can see the issue when you use `height` instead of `max-height`:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  position: relative;
}
nav:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
nav h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
nav #nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav label[for='nav-toggle']:after {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 4em;
  content: 'Menu';
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
nav #nav-toggle:checked ~ ul {
  height: 1000px;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
nav #nav-toggle:checked ~ label:after {
  content: 'Close';
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #337AB7;
}
nav li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active,
nav a:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #337AB7;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
  <label for="nav-toggle"></label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I totally missed that.  I knew setting it to an overkill number was going to bite me back.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to find a way to make it work without having to set an explicit height.  You can't transition from `height: 0` to `height: auto` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Change your transition code to something like this: `transition: max-height .3s ease-in-out;`

That will make it quicker as well as add the animation to dropdown, not just dropup.

EDIT:

```
nav ul {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 100ms ease;
}

nav #nav-toggle:checked ~ ul {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}
```

Try the above. The dropdown will have a nice smooth effect, but going back up will be quick with an unnoticeable delay.

The actual cause if this is beyond me. My guess is it's the fact that other code is being rendered before the transition since you have a click, an action, then the transition added to the action. That's just my guess though.

Comment: Thanks, that sure makes the closing animation better.  But there is still a tiny pause before closing that does not happen when opening.

Added updated jsfiddle link

Comment: Yes, I see that as well. I'll find a fix and update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netron/t4ny06Le/7/) - Only 1 line fix

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```